# Putting together Geolocation and Places search in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-geolocation

I have been trying to put together two of the functionalities the GoogleMaps API offers for developers(Places Search and Geolocation)

Since I'm not very familiar with javascript, I'm not positive what could be the mistake I'm making. So far, the Places Search is totally functional (with a predetermined location) but not so the Geolocation (which should overwrite the predetermined location with the user's location).

Here you can take a look at my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Place searches</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
        #map {
            height: 580px;
            width: 680px;
            border: 10px solid darkred;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 25px;
        }


        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
        // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
        // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

        var map;
        var infowindow;

        function initMap() {
            var pyrmont = {lat:43.364490, lng:-8.407406};

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: pyrmont,
                zoom: 15
            });

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map:map});
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch({
                location: pyrmont,
                radius: 2000,
                type: ['gym']
            }, callback);

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var pos = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };

                    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                    infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
                    map.setCenter(pos);
                }, function() {
                    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                });
            } else {
                // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }
        }

        function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');

        }

        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        function createMarker(place) {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Encuentra tu gimnasio más próximo</h1>
</header>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***MY_KEY***&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There seems te be an error with the casing of the `infoWindow` variable.

It's declared like this:

```
var infowindow;
```

But in the callback for `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is used with different casing:

```
infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
```

This error should have been shown in the browser's development tools console.